# variable values missing

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I have the following in database field

```
id = id,
Xterminal = 1234,
Testdata = 1234',
date BETWEEN $Date1 AND  $Date2,
MyVar = $myVar;
```

I want to use it in my sql statement. I have $Date1 = '2011-01-09' and $Date2 = '2011-03-09' set in my scripte above the sql statement.
I have $myvar setup to $myVar = 3. But it doesnt convert the variables in sql and when I do print_r on $sql it shows the variables and even in query it shows variables not the values of them

I doing the following

```
$conditions = explode(',',$results['conditions']);
```

print_r($condidtions) gives

Array
(
    [0] => 
id = id
    [1] => 
Xterminal = 1234
    [2] => 
Testdata = 1234
    [3] => 
date BETWEEN  $Date1 AND  $Date2
    [3] => 
MyVar = $myVar;

)

```
$sql1 = "Select * from table where ";
$sql2 = implode(' AND ',$conditions);

$sql = $Sql1.' '.$sql2;
```

print_r("$sql") gives

SELECT
    *
FROM

table
WHERE
id = id AND 
Xterminal = 1234 AND 
Testdata = 1234 AND 
date BETWEEN  $Date1 AND  $Date2 AND 
MyVar = $myVar;

Not sure why is it not taking my variable values that I have defined alreadt at the to of script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're saying is that the string `date BETWEEN $Date1 AND  $Date2,` came from the database.  If that is the case, then your variables are not being evaluated, because this is just data...

You can use eval(), but this is a dangerous path if users could possibly create these conditions.

```
$conditions = explode(',',$results['conditions']);
for ($x = 0; $x < count($conditions); $x++) {
    eval("\$conditions[\$x] = \"" . $conditions[$x] . "\";");
}
print_r($conditions);
```

Edit:  I put together a working PHP sample for this, visible at http://gfosco.kodingen.com/conditions.php and here is the source:

```
<?php

$conditions = array("date BETWEEN '\$Date1' AND '\$Date2',");

echo "\$conditions before the loop: <BR>";
var_dump($conditions);

$Date1 = '1/1/2011';
$Date2 = '12/31/2011';

echo "<BR>\$Date1 = " . $Date1 . "<BR>";
echo "\$Date2 = " . $Date2 . "<BR>";

for ($x = 0; $x < count($conditions); $x++) {
    eval("\$conditions[\$x] = \"" . $conditions[$x] . "\";");
}

echo "<BR>\$conditions after the loop:<BR>";
var_dump($conditions);
```

This outputs:

```
$conditions before the loop: 
array(1) { [0]=> string(35) "date BETWEEN '$Date1' AND '$Date2'," } 
$Date1 = 1/1/2011
$Date2 = 12/31/2011

$conditions after the loop:
array(1) { [0]=> string(41) "date BETWEEN '1/1/2011' AND '12/31/2011'," }
```

Comment: I tried eval around my variables in database, but now it prints eval($myVar) instead of value..am i missing something

Comment: @Autolycus I put together a working PHP example of this, the only change I made was putting single quotes around the date variables, otherwise they would not be valid in a SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
date BETWEEN {$Date1} AND  {$Date2},
```

No sure it will work since I can't see the way your variables are set in your script.